# Issues creating logo in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to recreate my logo with `HTML` and `CSS` as an exercise to learn more about rotations, transitions, and animations; I'm finding it rather tedious in regards to positioning and feel like I may be going about it the wrong way. Here a basic representation of my logo:

[image]

The `HTML` and `CSS` is pretty straight-forward so far, but as I stated it seems really tedious as any adjustment to heights or positions of `div` elements forces me to shift things around everywhere. I would prefer to have a parent `div` element that the logo fits in and resizes/repositions based on the parent.

I thought that `position: relative` would accomplish the repositioning, but I'm not sure how well using percentages will work for `width` and `height` attributes when it comes to this process.

Here is my current code; it is incomplete, but I wanted to seek more experienced advice prior to making it too far down the road and end up having to re-write the whole thing.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3CF;
  transform: rotatez(45deg);
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 500px;
}
.astick {
  width: 3px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #FC0;
  transform: rotatez(45deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: -8px;
  left: 460px;
}
.bstick {
  width: 3px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #8C3;
  transform: rotatez(-45deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: -45px;
  left: 460px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="astick"></div>
  <div class="bstick"></div>
  <div class="cstick"></div>
</div>
```

---

I'm wondering if there is a smarter, or more efficient way to accomplish this. When I say more efficient, I mean maintaining and reusing is simple and takes minimal time.

Also, what kind of issues will arise with animating the sizes of my elements for a nice transition effect? I believe just modifying the sizes will cause issues with positioning during the transitions, but I think I may not understand all of the potential issues.

---

### EDIT: Using SVG

I've decided based on the comments and answers already supplied that `SVG` is going to be a great decision to move forward with; I will assign a bounty of 50 to someone who writes up an incredibly detailed answer with regards to `SVG` that answers all of my concerns mentioned above.

- Positioning
- Scaling
- Animating
- Styling with CSS
- etc.

Comment: For a scalable, re-usable, code-based logo, using SVG should be your first choice. With it, you can also control and animate specific elements inside. A purely HTML/CSS logo may offer advantages when it comes to performance & browser compatibility, but it comes with spacing/scaling issues depending on how you built it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. SO is not a place where one _order_ a code piece and pay with a _bounty_. We help with existing code, so I suggest you make an effort of your own and come back asking for help with it if you can't make it work.

Comment: @LGSon I suggest you not be so rude to contributors; I am not asking for a code handout I've already crafted my working version with SVG thanks to the first answer suggesting its use. I am simply offering a bounty for a detailed answer for the sake of future readers as all of the examples below haven't addressed all of my concerns, nor have they made an in-depth effort to ensure future readers have all the related answers they need. I think you should make an effort to read the entire post prior to commenting to understand the entire situation.

Comment: First, telling someone to follow SO rules is not rude, second, can't see any effort of your own making an SVG version of your logo image. And how should someone, without writing up a code snippet, show how-to. If you want it in reading, it is already provided in the docs, e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/SVG so no reason for someone to write all that up again.

Comment: @LGSon Writing up a detailed answer is also part of SO rules, it's not a requirement, but we should all hold ourselves to that standard. I try to go above and beyond to provide a detailed answer for future readers, along with a thorough post for posing my question; at this point I think we're getting off topic and should just let the post be. The part that came off rude is your comment following how I may have misunderstood; that should have been rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
I'm using a div for the green line, a `::before` for the golden line and a `::after` for the blue square.

```css
.logo {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-top: 4px solid #8c3;
  transform:rotate(45deg) scale(.9,.9);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.logo::after,.logo::before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
  width:100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.logo::before{
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  border-left:4px solid #fc0;
}

.logo::after{
  height:100px;
  background-color:#3cf;
  right:0;
  top:-100px;
  border-bottom:4px solid #8c3;
  border-left:4px solid #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

I hope it helps.

#### update

However if SVG is in your mind I would do it like this:

In this case the SVG has a width declared in the CSS.

```css
line{stroke-width:4px}
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 215">
  <g transform="rotate(45)">
  <rect x="150" y="-100" width="100" height="100" fill="#3cf" />
  <line stroke="#8c3"  x2="250" />
  <line stroke="#fc0" x1="150" y1="-100" x2="150" y2="150" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Scaling:** When using SVG if your SVG has no `width` or `height` declared, it will take all the width available. So you can put it inside a container of the desired width. If the container will scale the SVG will take immediately the same size.

**Positioning:** An SVG element can be positioned like any other HTML *inline* element

**Styling** In the CSS I've set the `stroke-width` of the lines. If you need to change the colors, this also can be done in CSS. In this case I've used SVG transforms but I could have done it in CSS as well: `g{transform: rotate(45deg);}`

**Animations** you can animate SVG elements with [SMIL animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL), with CSS animations and with Javascript animations. In the case you want to animate your log please ask a question specifying how would you like to animate your SVG.

Comment: That's a cool alternative that definitely trims down on some of the tedious routes! +1

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example where I'm using SVG for the same result. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, three are many factors that effect the rotation function the start point, the page size, the width of the object, the length and also the direction. For SVG is good to read more about it here: https://svgontheweb.com/
 and https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/
https://www.jotform.com/blog/better-positioning-and-transforming-with-nested-svgs/

Here how to use it:

```html
 

 <svg width="450" height="250" style="background: gray">
  <g transform="rotate(45)">
  <rect x="150" y="-80" width="80" height="80" fill="#3cf" />
  <line stroke="#fc0"  x1="170"  x2="70"  />
  
  <line stroke="#fc0" x1="150" y1="-80" x2="150" y2="150" />
   <line stroke="#fc0" x1="70" y1="0" x2="70" y2="70" />
  
  </g>
</svg>
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3CF;
  transform: rotatez(45deg);
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 500px;
}
.astick {
  width: 3px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #FC0;
  transform: rotatez(45deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: -8px;
  left: 460px;
}
.bstick {
  width: 3px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #FC0;
  transform: rotatez(-45deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: 23px;
  left: 447px;
}

.astick1 {
  width: 3px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #FC0;
  transform: rotatez(45deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: -10px;
  left: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo" style=" position: center;">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="astick"></div>
  <div class="bstick"></div>
  <div class="cstick"></div>
   <div class="astick1"></div
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the write-up; however, I am looking for a detailed answer on reuse and scaling. I could have finished writing what I had to achieve what you've supplied here. Seems like SVG is going to be a better choice here.